# Windows service stop without errors

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I've created a simple Windows Service. It's my first try, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. Anyway, the service should start automatically, but it doesn't. It starts but then it get stopped automatically, without reporting any error. If I start it manually by the Computer Manager Window, it works fine and never get stopped...

I've also tryed to log the exceptions, but with no results.

That's the onStart() code:

```
Private _conn As SqlConnection
Private _connAttemps As Integer = 0

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Try

        tryConn() 'Tries to connect and report the connection object on success

        If _conn Is Nothing Then
            If _connAttemps = 3 Then
                Return
            Else
                setTimeout(Nothing, New Action(AddressOf tryConn), 10000, Nothing)
            End If
        End If

        ' Create a timer.
        Dim aTimer As Timer = New Timer()

        ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

        ' Set the Interval to 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 30000
        aTimer.Enabled = True
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim appLog As EventLog = New EventLog()
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists("WindowServiceProva") Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("WindowServiceProva", "WindowServiceProvaLog")
        End If
        appLog.Source = "WindowServiceProva"
        appLog.WriteEntry("Eccezione: " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And that's the installer:

```
Public Class myInstaller

    Private serviceInstaller As ServiceInstaller
    Private processInstaller As ServiceProcessInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'Chiamata richiesta da Progettazione componenti.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Aggiungere il codice di inizializzazione dopo la chiamata a InitializeComponent
        processInstaller = New ServiceProcessInstaller()
        serviceInstaller = New ServiceInstaller()

        'Service will run under system account
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem

        'Service will have Start Type of Manual
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic

        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "WindowServiceProva"

        'Per evitare che il servizio di interrompa
        serviceInstaller.DelayedAutoStart = True

        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller)
        Installers.Add(processInstaller)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: if it's to be started automatically, it will need a username/password with sufficient rights to run as a service.

Comment: Thank you @RBarryYoung for the reply. I tought using LocalSystem (`processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem`) as Account the service could start automatically anyway... Why it doesn't? In the msdn i read about LocalSystem: _An account, used by the service control manager, that has extensive privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network._ ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx)).

Comment: If other services are using it on the same system, then it should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, other services (not created by me) are running with LocalSystem account. I'm sorry but I can't understand your last question... How can I get the line you're talking about? I don't get any error or log!

Comment: The fact is I can manually start the service without errors... So your suggestion about permissions or other security settings could be right... But why and what I should fix?

Comment: You should be able to get something.  Even if your program cannot create any output, the Services Manager that tries to start it Automatically should be logging something to the event log, and when the process fails, there should also be something in the event log for that.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are logging Security Events on your system.  If it's a security failure, than that should give you something in the event log also.

Comment: Weird... Today I've powered on the pc and the service works well! Why? I'll try again tomorrow...